# Small descriptions next to matrix

Tags: matrices, brackets

One of my textbooks notates Markov transition matrices this way with 1 and 2 denoting states:

[image]

How can I reproduce this matrix in LaTeX?

Comment: The [`kbordermatrix` package](http://www.hss.caltech.edu/~kcb/LaTeX.shtml) is not on CTAN, but it can handle this beautifully. See the duplicate link. You can also change the delimiters, as described in the [`kbordermatrix` documentation](http://www.hss.caltech.edu/~kcb/TeX/kbordermatrix.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDITED to resolve the equation axis properly]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document}
\def\x{\begin{array}{c}x\\x\end{array}}
\(
\let\svarraycolsep\arraycolsep
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}
\arraycolsep 0.4ex
\begin{array}{c}
\\
\mathbb{P}=\quad\\
\\
\end{array}
\begin{array}{c}
 \\
 {\scriptstyle 1}\\
 {\scriptstyle 2}\\
\\
\end{array}
\begin{array}{c}
 \\
 \scalerel*[1.5ex]{(}{\x}\\
\\
\end{array}
\begin{array}{c}
 {\scriptstyle 1}\\
 1-a\\
 b\\
\\
\end{array}
\begin{array}{c}
 {\scriptstyle 2}\\
 a\\
 1-b\\
\\
\end{array}
\begin{array}{c}
 \\
 \scalerel*[1.5ex]{)}{\x}\\
\\
\end{array}
\mathrm{is~the~answer}
\arraycolsep\svarraycolsep
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.0}
\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One caveat with this approach is that your math axis is now slightly distorted. Visually you print `P=` between rows 2 and 3 of the matrix construction. If you add constructions on either side of this it will vertically align with the middle row (row 2), which would make `P=` seem off-axis.

Comment: @werner. True, but that can be circumvented by adding an extra [null] row each,to the bottom of the P+ as well as the matrix entries. No?

Comment: ...which you then have to compensate for regarding content (say, paragraphs) above/below. The space below this construction is then far greater than the space above...

Comment: @Werner: Uncle!

Comment: A long time without up votes!? Strange. +1.

Comment: @Sigur Thanks.  I hardly even remember this one.  Today, I'd be using stacks to tackle it.  Maybe next year, I'll ping you on my zero-vote answer from today ;^)  Cheers!